# Nginx reverse proxy to PHPMyAdmin returns 404

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, phpmyadmin

On my network I have two servers:

- One proxy-server (ip: `192.168.1.10`) using nginx to handle all incoming HTTP requests.
- One web-server (ip: `192.168.1.33`) running Apache2 and PHPMyAdmin

I want the proxy server to handle certain requests like this:

- `www.example.com` - leads to the Apache2 web-server
- `db.example.com` - leads to the PHPMyAdmin login-page

I have tried to configure nginx to do this by creating the following .conf-files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`:

www.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name www.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.33/;
  }

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

db.conf:

```
server {

  server_name db.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://192.168.1.33/phpmyadmin/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
  listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/db.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/db.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
  if ($host = db.example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name db.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Right now when I use `db.example.com` I get directed to the PHPMyAdmin login-page. However, the problem is that once I log in, the URL changes to `db.example.com/phpmyadmin/index.php` and it gives a 404 saying

> The requested URL /phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/index.php was not found on this server.

How can I make it possible to login through `db.example.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [`$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']`](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_PmaAbsoluteUri) in your phpMyAdmins config.inc.php:

> Sets here the complete URL (with full path) to your phpMyAdmin installation’s directory. E.g. https://www.example.net/path_to_your_phpMyAdmin_directory/. Note also that the URL on most of web servers are case sensitive (even on Windows). Don’t forget the trailing slash at the end.
>
> Starting with version 2.3.0, it is advisable to try leaving this blank. In most cases phpMyAdmin automatically detects the proper setting. **Users of port forwarding or complex reverse proxy setup might need to set this**.

(highlighting by me)

Setting this to `/` should do it.

```
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = '/';
```

Answer (score 0):

on the apache make sure that you made a virtual host db.domain.com which ponints to `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin`
and on .db conf

```
server {

  server_name db.domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://192.168.1.33/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
```